# How to solve "VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated"?

Tags: visual-studio, ipython, jupyter, pyzmq

When I use iPython to run some scripts, I've got the following warning message in iTerm:

> /Users/###/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/displayhook.py:12:
> VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
> Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.

When I try to run my code in Visual Studio Code, I've got the following error message:

[Error message in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeL7x.png)
[image]

I have already tried to update Anaconda, I have already tried to install nomkl with conda as well, without any success.

iTerm and VisualStudio on Mac OS 10.14.6, Anaconda up to date (4.7.12)

Answer (score -1):

### Remedy Option A)

Use **`anaconda`**-tools to separate an environment, say `aLastWorkingENV`, where you make use of `anaconda`-tooling to roll-back all components to a last working state, which does not whine about future deprecations. In such `aLastWorkingENV` environment, all thus synchronised programs will work smooth (as they did before a first component update, that has moved the stick)

### Remedy Option B)

Use **`anaconda`**-tools to update all current components and all their supporting modules and all packages versions `[ python, ipython, pyzmq, jupyter, ..., ]` to their most recent versions, where products QA coverage ought either confirm the PASS, or provide a remedy or workaround or the last-trouble-free version ( to eventually downgrade one such package, based on such exception, if present and relevant )

Either way, your code would stop throwing the soft-warnings and remain in such state, until any un-coordinated package update takes place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does option A) mean creating a virtual environment and (re)installing all the packages that I am using (each time I want to use iPython for a new project)? Regarding option B), if I have to downgrade one package, how could I know which one? I have already tried to update "all" packages with $ conda update --all, which is supposed to automatically downgrade packages when necessary... isn't it?

Comment: Option B) works supposing all package managers have already resolved the future deprecated ( colliding  ) syntax / feature / design. If not solved yet, you will face these warnings even with the most recent packages - check / report such collision(s) to the package maintainers. Option A) is best explained by anaconda documentation. Creating coherently working older versions is possible with following the dates of releases of the respective module/package. The rationale is not to mix versions, that do not work together. Conda environments are a simplest efficient tool for achieving this.